# Issue in running nodes locally

Tags: corda

When i run nodes locally using "./runnodes --log-to-console --logging-level=DEBUG" all the nodes and webservers starts successfully. But none of the operations work - for example, i need to submit a document for review - but when i do it does not submit. On investigating further it says

"Party named C=GB,L=London,O=AuthorisedAuthority cannot be found"

This works perfectly when we run from Intellij IDE. This issue occurs only when we run the nodes locally by generating the build. Any idea why this might be happening ?

This is the AuthorisedAuthority conf

```
extraAdvertisedServiceIds=[]
myLegalName="C=GB,L=London,O=AuthorisedAuthority"
networkMapService {
    address="localhost:10002"
    legalName="O=NetworkMapAndNotary,L=London,C=GB"
}
p2pAddress="localhost:10005"
rpcAddress="localhost:10006"
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[]
        user=user1
    }
]
webAddress="localhost:10007"
```

and this is one of the parties conf

```
extraAdvertisedServiceIds=[]
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
networkMapService {
    address="localhost:10002"
    legalName="O=NetworkMapAndNotary,L=London,C=GB"
}
p2pAddress="localhost:10008"
rpcAddress="localhost:10009"
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[]
        user=user1
    }
]
webAddress="localhost:10010"
```

Do I have to add AuthorisedAuthority to mapped services on parties conf files ?

Comment: Can you check each node’s node.conf file to ensure there really is a node with this name?

Comment: Can you post your configuration?

Comment: @MonoThreaded have edited my question with the conf files

Comment: I am surprised you leave no room for H2 port. Is there a chance you could reuse the same DB across nodes?

Comment: I tried this https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/corda-configuration-file.html but it does not work. Can you please point me to the correct sample or documentation. Because what i posted above was the auto generated conf file.

Comment: It's fine not to have an H2 port. How are you generating these nodes? Is this Corda 2 or Corda 3?

Comment: I am doing this with Corda 2.

Comment: @joel We are generating the nodes through deployNodes, is there anyother alternate method to generate or check ?

Comment: @Karthik I'd suggest running a standard CorDapp (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example) and seeing if that works. If it does, there's an issue with your config. If not, check the node logs for further error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Karthik & Param sent me their log files, and on both nodes I notice Artemis AMQP error messages, and since I believe this is all running on Karthik's laptop I am guessing he has a network configuration issue (maybe port contention or a loopback problem?).   Here are some extracts of the messages I found:

**from logs_AuthorisedAuthority node**

```
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:43:46,473Z [Thread-152 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@6ab6ec33)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64753 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
…
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:43:46,724Z [Thread-152 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@6ab6ec33)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64776 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
…
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,412Z [Thread-34 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.bindingRemovalArtemisMessageHandler - Detected RPC client disconnect on address rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.5531407695173593983, scheduling for reaping
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,443Z [Thread-156 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@6ab6ec33)] messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.callback - Queue deleted: rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.5531407695173593983 for rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.5531407695173593983
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,453Z [Thread-156 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@6ab6ec33)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64850 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,473Z [Thread-156 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@6ab6ec33)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64809 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,413Z [Thread-17 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] ssl.SslHandler.debug - [id: 0x1604b916, L:/127.0.0.1:64847 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:10002] Swallowing a harmless 'connection reset by peer / broken pipe' error that occurred while writing close_notify in response to the peer's close_notify
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
                at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_162] …
```

**(from logs_PartyA node) - more output provided to show the effect**

```
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:43:45,890Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64755 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
…
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:43:46,498Z [Thread-33 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.bindingRemovalArtemisMessageHandler - Detected RPC client disconnect on address rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751, scheduling for reaping
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:43:46,513Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.callback - Queue deleted: rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751 for rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:43:46,557Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64782 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
…
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:39,752Z [Thread-153 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64805 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:39,711Z [activemq-failure-check-thread] impl.RemotingServiceImpl.removeConnection - RemotingServiceImpl::removing connection ID 6109884
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:39,826Z [activemq-failure-check-thread] impl.RemotingServiceImpl.removeConnection - RemotingServiceImpl::removing connection ID 2112730322
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:39,826Z [activemq-failure-check-thread] impl.RemotingServiceImpl.removeConnection - RemotingServiceImpl::removing connection ID -1877387306
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:39,860Z [Thread-14 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] impl.ChannelImpl.invokeInterceptors - Invocation of interceptor org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.ClusterManager$IncomingInterceptorLookingForExceptionMessage on PACKET(Ping)[type=10, channelID=0, packetObject=Ping, connectionTTL=60000] returned true
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,185Z [Thread-153 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] impl.PostOfficeImpl.route - Message CoreMessage[messageID=2147490245,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=0,expiration=0, durable=true, address=internal.activemq.notifications,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_RoutingName=rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751,_AMQ_Distance=0,_AMQ_ConsumerCount=0,_AMQ_User=SystemUsers/Node,_AMQ_SessionName=c9ebe05c-2d37-11e8-a4ed-a45e60dbc6b5,_AMQ_Address=rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751,_AMQ_RemoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:64805,_AMQ_NotifType=CONSUMER_CLOSED,_AMQ_FilterString=NULL-value,_AMQ_NotifTimestamp=1521658780083,_AMQ_ClusterName=rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.24820540069285857515643c665-2796-11e8-87f6-a45e60dbc6b5]]@75549228 is not going anywhere as it didn't have a binding on address:internal.activemq.notifications
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,414Z [Thread-32 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.bindingRemovalArtemisMessageHandler - Detected RPC client disconnect on address rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751, scheduling for reaping
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,445Z [Thread-153 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.callback - Queue deleted: rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751 for rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,451Z [Thread-153 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64806 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T18:59:40,480Z [Thread-153 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64846 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
…
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T19:12:26,631Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64999 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T19:12:27,025Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64970 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T19:12:27,108Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:64963 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T19:12:27,178Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] impl.PostOfficeImpl.route - Message CoreMessage[messageID=2147490272,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=0,expiration=0, durable=true, address=internal.activemq.notifications,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_RoutingName=rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751,_AMQ_Distance=0,_AMQ_ConsumerCount=0,_AMQ_User=SystemUsers/Node,_AMQ_SessionName=026eaa11-2d3a-11e8-a4ed-a45e60dbc6b5,_AMQ_Address=rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751,_AMQ_RemoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:64963,_AMQ_NotifType=CONSUMER_CLOSED,_AMQ_FilterString=NULL-value,_AMQ_NotifTimestamp=1521659547171,_AMQ_ClusterName=rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.24820540069285857515643c665-2796-11e8-87f6-a45e60dbc6b5]]@1667224141 is not going anywhere as it didn't have a binding on address:internal.activemq.notifications
[WARN ] 2018-03-21T19:12:27,485Z [Thread-33 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.bindingRemovalArtemisMessageHandler - Detected RPC client disconnect on address rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751, scheduling for reaping
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T19:12:27,503Z [Thread-159 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@321558f8)] messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.callback - Queue deleted: rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751 for rpc.client.SystemUsers/Node.2482054006928585751
[DEBUG] 2018-03-21T19:12:27,499Z [Thread-15 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] ssl.SslHandler.debug - [id: 0x9433fcde, L:/127.0.0.1:65037 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:10002] Swallowing a harmless 'connection reset by peer / broken pipe' error that occurred while writing close_notify in response to the peer's close_notify
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
                at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_162] …
```